# Order year in rails date_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
f.date_select(:birthday, prompt: {
                  day: 'Select day', month: 'Select month', year: 'Select year'
                  }, end_year: Time.now.year-13, start_year: 1900, required: true)
```

It shows start_year first and end_year last:
1900
1901
..
..
2002

I want 2002 first and 1900 at the bottom of the select box.
Couldn't find anything in rails documentation and google. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: set end_year to `1900` and start_year to `Time.now.year - 13`

Comment: Why didn't I think about that?!! i am an idiot lol, Thanks a lot Athar. Can you please write that in answer field so that i can accept that as right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply exchanging `end_year` and `start_year` will do the trick.

In your case:

```
f.date_select(:birthday, prompt: {
              day: 'Select day', month: 'Select month', year: 'Select year'
              }, end_year: 1900, start_year: Time.now.year-13, required: true)
```